Error message: "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota)." with Gemini multimodal
I'm trying using Gemini-1.5-pro-preview-0409 using the GCP console webui ( https://console.cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative/multimodal/ ); my prompt includes an embedded PDF with scanned images of documents.
For some PDFs it works fine but when I use larger PDFs it starts streaming the response (I can see it in the browser!) but at some point it stops and shows a modal with:
Failed to submit prompt
Error message: "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota)."

Status: 429 Error code: 8

Request ID: 2751451571636418810

The prompt size seems to be 20760 tokens (according to the web ui); the Output token limit is set to 8192.
I'm not sure which resource quota is being exhausted; I understand Gemini should be able to handle this 4mb pdfs and much more!)

I ran into the same error. I think that there is an unstated limit of 32 pages for PDF documents.

The free plan limits are very limited, and you probably need to upgrade to a Paid plan. You can do it at the API Keys page of the Google AI Studio.


Check here for possible reasons: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/best-practices/quotas?hl=en

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
